# JavaCV - FrameGrabber.createDefault() function is undefined

Tags: java, javacv

I'm trying to use JavaCV for the first time but I got an error when I'm using

```
FrameGrabber.createDefault(0);
```

The error said

> **The method is undefined for the type FrameGrabber**

FYI, I got the javaCV jar from here - http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjavacvjar.htm

here's my little source :

```
public void run(){
        FrameGrabber grabber = null;

        System.out.println("Initializing grabber for " + videoInput.getDeviceName(0) + " ...");
        try {
          grabber = FrameGrabber.createDefault(0);
          grabber.setFormat("dshow");       // using DirectShow
          grabber.setImageWidth(WIDTH);     // default is too small: 320x240
          grabber.setImageHeight(HEIGHT);
          grabber.start();
        }
        catch(Exception e) 
        {  System.out.println("Could not start grabber");  
           System.out.println(e);
           System.exit(1);
        }
}
```

And i follow the step from here https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/12/hand-and-finger-detection-using-javacv.html

Can anyone help me how to fix this?

Comment: Could you share more details in terms of logs and sources of the jar that you're using and confirm if the imported class FrameGrabber has the method `createDefault(int)`

Answer (score 0):

just Check build path and reference library for javacv.